# addEventListener on dynamicaly created elements vs addEventListener on already existing elements in the DOM (and general mechanism of addEventHandler)

Tags: javascript

***Description***

In my example,for the HTML part, i have an `input` and a `button` right next to it and under those a `paragraph`, followed by an `unordered list` at the bottom.

Typing in the input area and pressing enter, adds a new list item.

At the top of the JavaScript code, i have an eventlistener, triggered by any keyboard input.
Clicking on the button(doubleclick), paragraph or the dynamicaly added list items, will display a message(the element type-name) in the console area.

***Behavior***

Lets say i **type the word *yess*** in the input field. Then i sumbit it **pressing enter**. That is total of **5 keyboard inputs** and so i when i click the **`paragraph`(click)** or the **`button`(dblclick)** **i get the console message 5 times** each time i click or the paragraph or each time i double click the button. However, clicking on the **`list item`(click)** that was just created, no matter if i press more keys, **the message only appears** to be unique, so only **1** **time**.

***Question***

So my question is, why is it only one message and why 5 messages? I would like to know the **mechanism of action behind all this program**, including the 5 messages when i type 5 times.
(Also about the single message, im suspecting its because for every keyup event, the `const li` is unique every time(since its inside the code block). Because having it (the `const li`) outside of the code block, and then trying to add list items, it only  adds 1 on the first enter hit, and then updates the same `li`. And so, when i click on it, it prints 5 messages in the console area.)

*Better to be run in **full page** for it to be fully visible.*

https://jsfiddle.net/hj2e18f6/23/

```js
const inpt = document.querySelector("#inpt");
/* const li = document.createElement("li"); */

inpt.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

  const par = document.querySelector("#par");
  const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const list = document.querySelector("#list");

  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    li.innerHTML = inpt.value;
    list.appendChild(li);
  }


  par.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
    console.log("p");
  });
  li.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
    console.log("li");
  });
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("btn");
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="inpt">
  <button id="btn"></button>
  <p id="par">par</p>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the element you already have added an event listener, you don't need to add another one. On every key up, the eventlisteners for the objects that already exist are adding up. So I changed your code here:

```js
const inpt=document.querySelector("#inpt");
const li = document.createElement("li");

const par = document.querySelector("#par");
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

par.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
  console.log("p");
});

li.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
  console.log("li");
});

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("btn");
});

inpt.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    
        const li = document.createElement("li");
    const list= document.querySelector("#list");
    
    if(event.keyCode === 13){
        li.innerHTML= inpt.value;
            list.appendChild(li);
    } 
    
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="inpt">
  <button id="btn"></button>
  <p id="par">par</p>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, i understand its adding up. I just want to understand the behavior of that additive stacking and the singular message on the dynamicaly created element.

Comment: Because you create a new `li` element on every keyup, so the event listener is being applied to a new `li` each time. However the button event listener is being applied to the same element, which is why it's stacking up.

Comment: Is there any techincallity behind this stacking? Any particular mechanism of action (some short explanation)?

Comment: If you run `element.addEventListener(...)` on an element 10 times, it will add 10 event listeners. Even if those event listeners do exactly the same thing. So if each of those event listeners run `console.log` on click, then you'll get 10 `console.logs` on every click.

Comment: This was a very random post from me, but thanks for helping. Just had to make sure i wasn't missing on some techincality and moving along with JS with false understandings.